# Advantage of using memcachier vs ordinary Rails.cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, memorycache, memcachier

I came across with this article https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcachier

I just want to ask what's the main advantage of storing the cache in memcachier.
What's the advantage of using other service for caching compared to just caching on server itself?

Does it have any particular advantage when caching at low level in Rails??

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `compared to just caching on server itself`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some advantages:

- Imagine you have multiple servers and all servers should use the same cache.
- You do not want to have the cache on the same server than the webserver.
- Or you do not want to maintain a memcached (or something like that) installation yourself.